# gnugk and openmcu

Tags: voip

I am trying to use gnugk and openmcu for a video conferencing application.
As per my configuration, both gnugk as well as openmcu run in same machine ( 10.21.34.2).

But after seeing the log files, I could discern that openmcu is not able to register with the gatekeeper, it says something like this...

```
2011/06/27 17:18:26.868       OpenMCU   Debug3  RAS Gatekeeper discovered at: 10.21.34.2:1719 (if=10.21.34.2:36799) 
2011/06/27 17:18:26.868       OpenMCU   Debug3  RAS Cannot register with Gatekeeper without a H323Listener!
2011/06/27 17:18:26.869       OpenMCU   Error   Error registering with gatekeeper at ""
```

The issue as it seems to me is because of the second line....H323 Listener..

Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both GnuGk and OpenMCU are listening on port 1720.

Change the RAS listener for OpenMCU to a different port (eg. 1730). Then it will be able to register with GnuGk.

In your OpenMCU config file:

```
[Parameters]
Interface Array Size=1
Interface 1=10.21.34.2:1730
Gatekeeper=10.21.34.2
```